# Can't the dataframe from read_sql in the Spyder Variable Explorer

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, spyder

So, I am trying to read a table from the SQL server database using pandas.read_sql, but it showed this warning when I clicked the dataframe in the variable explorer on Spyder (5.0):

```
Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console.
The error message was:
An error occurred, see the console..

Note: Please don't report this problem on Github, there's nothing to do about it.
```

[image: Spyder Variable Explorer Warning]

The code I tried is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
server = 'My_IP' 
database = 'my_db' 
username = 'my_username' 
password = 'my_password' 
connection = ('mssql+pyodbc://'+username+':'+password+'@'+server+'/'+database+'?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server')
engine = create_engine(connection)
df= pd.read_sql('Table_Name', engine)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The message you posted above (i.e. `Spyder was unable to retrieve ...`) is incomplete. Please post the full message or (better yet) an image that shows the message. Without that we can correctly explain you why that message is shown. Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, I reposted the image. I removed the picture as previous comment asked.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I thought the message was incomplete. The error could be caused by your dataframe being too large. How many rows and columns does it have?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, the dataframe is only around 2100 rows and 4 columns

Comment: Then it's probably an issue with Spyder being unable to transfer your dataframe from the kernel to the Variable Explorer for inspection. Unfortunately, we don't have an easy way to test this, sorry.